# Configuring connection pool with mybatis + spring

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using mybatis configured with spring. Everything works fine but with this configuration there's not connection pool. Every time I execute some SQL statement it creates a new connection. Is there any simple way how to configure connection pool with mybatis + spring?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
         http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">

        <mybatis:scan base-package="test.mapper" />

        <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:test/mybatis.xml" />
            <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:test/mapper/*.xml" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="personMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
            <property name="mapperInterface" value="test.mapper.ScenarioMapper" />
            <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasourceorg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="TEST"/>
        <property name="password" value="test123"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Comment: You haven't configured a connection but rather the `DriverManagerDataSource`. Just confiugre a proper connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my configuration，I used druid as the connection pool：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.itcast.customer"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />
    <bean name="dataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath:cn/itcast/customer/dao/CustomerMapper.xml" />
    </bean>


    <bean name="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="cn.itcast.customer.dao"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```